# office.js web add in authenticate to third party web-app

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

im playing around with the starter outlook web add in template in visual studio 2019.
Need some security advise
inside ***MessageRead.js*** I can use **Office.context.mailbox.userProfile** to get some info about the add in user profile
***For example:*** userDisplayName, userEmailAddress, ***id***, and so much more.

im wondering if its a bad idea to use ***"id"*** as a form of SSO authentication method with my third party web application.

I would initially ask the user to authenticate with email+password+ID from Office.context.mailbox.userProfile, then store the ID with the userRecord inside my database.

Next time the user opens the outlook add in it will automatically login with "only" the id from Office.context.mailbox.userProfile

Question is: is this totally unsafe and should not be used ?
trying to avoid the oAuth method and finding more simple approach.

if this is a bad idea, can you show me example of simple secure method.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended way to get user ID and map to user in add-in backend is to get user token and use ID from it. Please refer to docuemntation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token